# React POST request without form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to familiarize myself with sending POST data, this time using React. In this instance, I am attempting to do it without a form.

My front-end React code specifically looks like so:

```
stockconfirmbuy: function(){
var stin = this.refs.stockpriceref.innerHTML;
  var totalbuyval = stin * this.state.stockdnum;    
    return (<div>
    <p>Are you sure you would like to buy {this.refs.stocknameref.innerHTML} stock at ${this.refs.stockpriceref.innerHTML} per share?</p>
    <p>Select Amount:</p>
    <input className="form-control" defaultValue="1" type="number" value={this.state.stockdum} onChange={this.changestocknum} /> 
    <p>Your Total:</p>
    <p>${totalbuyval}</p>        
    <div id="buttongroups">
    <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.buyprocess}>Buy It</button>
    <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.cancelprocess}>Cancel</button>
    </div>
</div>);
},
```

My initial `stockdnum` state value is 1, for clarity's sake.

Meanwhile, my schema is arranged like so:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({

  email: { type: String, unique: true, lowercase: true},
  password: String,
    icapital: {type: Number, default: 9001},
  profile: {
    name: { type: String, default: ''},
    picture: { type: String, default: ''}
  },
  address: String,
  history: [{
    date: Date,
    stocklabel: String,
    stockname: String,
    stocknumber: Number,
    stockpaid: Number
  }]
});
```

My attempt at coding the transaction into my `routes/user.js` page looks like so:

```
router.post('/profile', function(req, res, next) {
  User.findOne({ _id: req.user._id }, function(err, user) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    if (req.body.stocklabel) user.history.stocklabel = req.body.stocklabel;
    if (req.body.stockname) user.history.stockname = req.body.stockname;
    user.history.date = Date();
    if (req.body.stocknumber) user.history.stocknumber = req.body.stocknumber;
    if (req.body.stockprice) user.history.stockprice = req.body.stockprice;
    user.save(function(err) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      req.flash('success', 'Purchase sucessful');
      return res.redirect('/profile');
    });
  });
});
```

First, I would like to make sure that my transaction lines up with the arrangement of my Schema.

Second, going back to my front-end React code, I am not sure how to take the relevant data from my React into my DB. I want the operation to run on `{this.buyprocess}`. However, since it is not a traditional input form, I am unsure how to turn it into a submit button that transfers these following pieces of info.

`{this.refs.stockpriceref.innerHTML}` repressents the stock label.

`{this.state.stockdnum}` represents the amount, or the stock number.

`{totalbuyval}` represents the total cost, or the stock price.

I am not sure what the code in the `this.buyprocess` function would look like.

Comment: Could you isolate your post to single question? You mixing up frontend with backend, and that way you don't have a real question, instead you asking to  finish task for you. If you are interested how to send POST with react, you should not mention schema, nodejs, etc. 
Ex. I want to POST request with this body. OR how can I transfer values from react form and send it via POST request. 
P.S. You should start with React questions, cause your React snippet looks like a bad try to use Jquery techniques. Refs should be avoided in React, and instead of them State should be used

Comment: I just worry that these variables aren't clear enough without a full example.  But yes, I'll look back at my question to see if I can focus it more.

Comment: you should change backend/database mention for simple request you need to send. When you will be able to send request from React, then you could start to think how to manage it on backend. Try to separate tasks for yourself, and make it step by step

Comment: Possibly [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39298644/using-post-in-react-without-form/39299464#39299464) may help.